# Using .load() to add HTML form have some issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i am creating login web app using ajax and PHP and i use javascript an php to validate the input and it works for the login form,but i added a link under the form if not signed up before [the link under form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV9vP.png)
and the HTML for it is :

```
 <a href="#" onclick="signUpForm()">don't have account on tobe?</a>
```

and the signUpForm() function contain

```
function signUpForm(){
    $(".logInForm").load("SignUpForm.html");
}
```

and it works the content change 
but when i use JS to validate input using code (just like the login code witch is working) :
HTML(the input in the SignUpForm.html calls the signUp() function)

```
<input type="button" value="Sign Up" onclick="signUp()">

function signUp(){
    if($("input[class='user']").val()==""|| $("input[class='pass']").val()==""){
        $(".error-message").fadeIn();
        document.getElementById("error-message").innerHTML="Please fill all fields";
    } else{
     //action(2) including the php file loading 
    } 
}
```

what happen is javascript ignores the new input fields and consider that the are deleted and always go to action(2) how can i make js see the new form html?

Comment: so how is `function signUp()` being called? and where are the inputs?

Comment: you also tagged as php but no code to support the question.

Comment: in a button input in the signUpForm.html

Comment: here it is `<input type="button" value="Sign Up" onclick="signUp()">`

Comment: A little more context would be helpful. Can you create a [Codepen](http://codepen.io) that duplicates the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand your problem correctly, I think this code should help you get on the right footing (http://codepen.io/trevorhreed/pen/bppxRG?editors=1010).

In this example, I'm using `$(...).html(...)` instead of `$(...).load(...)` since I don't have a server hosting HTML files, but it should work fine to swap `.html(...)` out for `.load(...)`.

```js
console.clear();
$(function(){
  var placeholder = $('#placeholder'),
      signInTpl = $('#signin').html(),
      signUpTpl = $('#signup').html();
   
  function goToSignIn(){
    placeholder.html(signInTpl);
    // or placeholder.load('signin.html');
    var btnSignIn = $('#btnSignIn'),
        signInUsername = $('#signinUsername'),
        signInPassword = $('#signinPassword');
    btnSignIn.on('click', function(){
      if(signInUsername.val() == '' || signInPassword.val() == ''){
        alert('Sign In form is NOT valid');
      }else{
        alert('Sign In form is valid');
      }
    })
  }
  
  function goToSignUp(){
    placeholder.html(signUpTpl);
    // or placeholder.load('signup.html');
    var btnSignUp = $('#btnSignUp'),
        signUpUsername = $('#signupUsername'),
        signUpPassword = $('#signupPassword');
    btnSignUp.on('click', function(){
      if(signUpUsername.val() == '' || signUpPassword.val() == ''){
        alert('Sign Up form is NOT valid');
      }else{
        alert('Sign Up form is valid');
      }
    })
  }
  
  goToSignIn();
    
  $('#btnGoToSignUp').on('click', function(){
    goToSignUp();
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<template id="signin">
  <h2>Sign In</h2>
  <form method="post">
    <label>
      Username
      <input id="signinUsername" />
    </label>
    <label>
      Password
      <input id="signinPassword" />
    </label>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btnGoToSignUp">Sign Up</a>
    <button type="button" id="btnSignIn">Sign In</button>
  </form>
</template>
<template id="signup">
  <h2>Sign Up</h2>
  <form method="post">
    <label>
      Username
      <input id="signupUsername" />
    </label>
    <label>
      Password
      <input id="signupPassword" />
    </label>
    <button type="button" id="btnSignUp">Sign In</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

Comment: great you understood my problem and your code is working well but the point is i am using external html file containing the form code,not in the same file.

Comment: This code will work with .html(...) or with .load(...)

Comment: I added comments to the code to make it a little easier to see how you could use `.load(...)` in this example instead of `.html(...)` (external files instead of templates).